# Can Angular forRoot method return forRoot from another module?

Tags: angular, angular-module

I'm wondering if static method forRoot can return forRoot invocation from another module?

I've just configured ngrx store and want to avoid having many imports in app.module so I created ConfiguredStoreModule and in forRoot method I return StoreModule.forRoot(config). Everything works but does this aproach break any good practices or conventions?
Another advantage of this is possibility to register providers that have been used in effects and they should be singletons. Everything is in one place.

```
// ConfiguredStore.module.ts
import {ModuleWithProviders, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {metaReducers, reducers} from './index';
import {StoreModule} from '@ngrx/store';
import {TestService} from './my-budgets/test.service';
import {myBudgetsEffects} from './my-budgets/effects';
import {EffectsModule} from '@ngrx/effects';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [

  ]
})
export class ConfiguredStoreModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders[] {
    return [
      StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {metaReducers}),
      EffectsModule.forRoot([...myBudgetsEffects, /*...effects from another folder*/]),
      {
        ngModule: ConfiguredStoreModule,
        providers: [TestService]
      },
    ]
  }
```

### }

```
// AppModule
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {ScrollToModule} from '@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to';
import {StoreModule} from '@ngrx/store';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {CoreModule} from './modules/core/core.module';
import 'lodash';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { reducers, metaReducers } from './store';
import {ConfiguredStoreModule} from './store/store.module';


export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule,
    //StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),
    ConfiguredStoreModule.forRoot(),
    !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : [],
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: one module can share its components, services, and other imported modules if they are exported, in this case you won't need to import them again in the other module, but to answer your question, i don't think this is the purpose of forRoot, its used to tell which is the main module that the app should start at, that's why you can't have 2 forRoot

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
// ConfiguredStore.module.ts
import {ModuleWithProviders, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {metaReducers, reducers} from './index';
import {StoreModule} from '@ngrx/store';
import {TestService} from './my-budgets/test.service';
import {myBudgetsEffects} from './my-budgets/effects';
import {EffectsModule} from '@ngrx/effects';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    EffectsModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    EffectsModule
  ]
})
export class ConfiguredStoreModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders[] {
    return [
      StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {metaReducers}),
      EffectsModule.forRoot([...myBudgetsEffects, /*...effects from another folder*/]).providers,
      {
        ngModule: ConfiguredStoreModule,
        providers: [TestService]
      },
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Angular 9, you have to [explicitly provide the type of `ModuleWithProviders`](https://angular.io/guide/migration-module-with-providers). This should work:

```
static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<ConfiguredStoreModule> {
    return {
        ngModule: ConfiguredStoreModule,
        providers: [
            TestService,
            StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }).providers,
            EffectsModule.forRoot([...myBudgetsEffects, /*...effects from another folder*/]).providers,
        ]
    };
}
```